# ng-if expression always renders true

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use the ng-if expression to render posts as images or text, depending on the content. The first of theese lines render true sometimes and false sometimes in a ng-repeat-loop, however both the image and the span are shown in each itteration.

```
<a href="{{post.url}}">
  {{post.type == 0}}
  <img ng-if="post.type == 0" src="{{post.content}}" />
   <span ng-if="post.type == 1">{{post.content}}<span>
</a>
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vKUB7aeHR6enDfOxXL5i?p=preview

Comment: Can you post the data structure of the posts?

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the value of "post.type" to equal 0 or 1. Use the "==" operator to determine if the value is equal to the comparison

```
<a href="{{post.url}}">
  {{post.type = 0}}
  <img ng-if="post.type == 0" src="{{post.content}}" />
   <span ng-if="post.type == 1">{{post.content}}<span>
</a>
```

A different approach:

```
{{post.type = 1}}
<a ng-if="post.type == 0" href="#"><img ng-if="post.type == 0" src="{{post.content}}" /></a>
<a ng-if="post.type == 1"><span>{{post.content}}</span></a>
```

Comment: Set up a plunker for further debugging. I'd probably approach the overall solution to your dilemma differently.

Comment: For example, I'd probably use ng-if on two different a elements rather than the inner html of the a element.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like this:

ng-if="post.type == '0'"

Answer (score -2):

1. Sometimes in a complex HTML not closing tags can create an issue and your span isn't closed (no ).
2. Just for a test case try to change to ng-show.
3. JB Nizet gave u a working plnkr in the comments so I think there is an issue before that.